# How to define integral arguments in R? (argument "a" is missing, with no default)

Tags: python, r

I am trying to recreate a python code in R, but no matter what I try I get the error message.

This is my python code which works

```py
def Cp(T,a,b,c):
    return a+b*T+c*(T**2)
a = np.array([26.63, 20.04, 13.39])
b = np.array([0.183, 0.0945, 0.077])
c = -np.array([45.86, 30.95, 18.71])*(10**(-6))
Tp = 298
Tk = 1035
RE = np.array([0, 1, 2])
Cps1 = [(1/(Tk-Tp))*si.romberg(Cp, Tp, Tk, args=(a[i], b[i], c[i])) for  i in RE]
Cps1
```

This is how I have tried to do this in R

```
Cp <- function(Te,a,b,c) a+b*Te+c*(Te**2)
a1 <- c(26.63, 20.04, 13.39)
b1 <- c(0.183, 0.0945, 0.077)
c1 <- -c(45.86, 30.95, 18.71)*(10**(-6))
Tp <- 298
Tk <- 1035
require(pracma)
for(i in seq(1,3,1)){
  Cps1[i] <- (1/(Tk-Tp))*integral(Cp, Tp, Tk, a=a1[i], b=b1[i], c=c1[i])
}
Cps1
```

In python I get this

```
[126.15165675333331, 67.87464798333333, 55.55221070333332]
```

But in R I get an error:

> argument "a" is missing, with no default

Comment: For exponentiation in R use the caret operator (`^`). Sorry I'm on the move so can't try reproducing the problem to see if this actually was the issue.

Comment: @VictorOrdu Yes, but so is the double asterisk, try `2**3`.

Comment: You have `Tk <- T0` but `T0` is not defined.

Comment: @Rui Baradas Oh really?  Good to know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is because `a = a1[i]` matches the argument of `integral` which starts by `a`, namely `abstol`.

So a solution is to specify `abstol`:

```
integral(Cp, Tp, Tk, abstol=0, a=a1[1], b=b1[1], c=c1[1])
# 92973.77
```

This matches the Python result:

```
> 92973.77/(Tk-Tp)
[1] 126.1517
```

---

#### Explanation

There's a coding error in the `pracma::integral` function. This function uses `match.fun` in a way similar to the function `I1` below:

```
I1 <- function(f, abstol=0, ...){
  f <- match.fun(f)
  ff <- function(x) f(x, ...)
  ff(1)
}

f <- function(x, a) x + a

I1(f, a = 2)
# Error in f(x, ...) : argument "a" is missing, with no default
```

The correct way to code such a situation is to put the argument `...` before the other arguments:

```
I2 <- function(f, ..., abstol=0){
  f <- match.fun(f)
  ff <- function(x) f(x, ...)
  ff(1)
}

f <- function(x, a) x + a

I2(f, a = 2)
# 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can vary the extra parameter inputs explicitly in the loop, and change your original function

```
require(pracma)

Cp <- function(Te) {
  a + b * Te + c * (Te**2)
}

a1 <- c(26.63, 20.04, 13.39)
b1 <- c(0.183, 0.0945, 0.077)
c1 <- -c(45.86, 30.95, 18.71) * (10**(-6))
Tp <- 298
Tk <- 1035
Cps1 = NA

for(i in 1:3){
  a = a1[i]
  b = b1[i]
  c = c1[i]
  Cps1[i] = (1 / (Tk - Tp)) * integral(Cp, Tp, Tk)
t}

Cps1 

[1] 126.15166  67.87465  55.55221
```

Answer (score 0):

Like user @StéphaneLaurent says in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56409369/how-to-define-integral-arguments-in-r-argument-a-is-missing-with-no-default/56409577#56409577), I also believe it's because argument `a` is matching `abstol`.
Another way of solving this problem is to change the `Cp` function argument name to `A`.

```
Cp <- function(x, A, b, c) A + b*x + c*(x**2)

Cps1 <- numeric(3)
for(i in seq(1, 3, 1)){
  res <- integral(Cp, xmin = Tp, xmax = Tk, method = "Kronrod",
                  A = a1[i], b = b1[i], c = c1[i])
  Cps1[i] <- (1/(Tk-Tp))*res
}

Cps1
#[1] 126.15166  67.87465  55.55221
```

Comment: Yes. Now I understand why the `integrate` function starts with `f <- match.fun(f)`. The author of `pracma` should add this line to `integral`.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Actually, there *is* a `fun <- match.fun(fun)` on line 9. So I really don't understand the error.

Comment: I have investigated. The problem with `integral` is that `abstol` is prior to `...`.

Comment: See my answer again. I have added the conclusion of my investigation.